# How do you set the variable for the background-color of a selected paper-menu link?

Tags: polymer, polymer-starter-kit

The starter-kit has regular links inside the drawer paper-menu, not paper-items. To style the background-color of a selected paper-menu link, the --paper-menu-selected-item css mixin can't be set to a different color for the paper-menu in app-theme.html. Directly styling paper-menu a.iron-selected class isn't working either, however.
What is the standard way of setting the background-color, then?

Edit: 
Ok, this seems to be set to the --light-primary-color custom property. Does anybody know where this is set? Didn't find the docs for it.

Answer (score 1):

`--light-primary-color` is located in `polymer-starter-kit/app/styles/app-theme.html`

Comment: Yes, that is where you change it. But where is it exposed as the background-color for the selected menu link?

Comment: Oh, my bad. It's set in the shared-styles.html imported in the index file. Why didn't I look there??